# Check Multiple Conditions In ternary operator in c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have three variables

```
int a =10;
int b=20;
int c=30;
int d=0;
```

Now the thing i want to do that i want to use ternary operator and assign the
greatest among (a,b,c) into "d" . Thanks in advance

Comment: Almost the same question was asked yeterday.  Homework/term paper?

Comment: google , but dont find any solution .

Comment: Is that homework? Then tag it so.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Math.Max` to achieve your goal:

```
   int d = Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c))
```

Of course, you can also use the ternary operator, but it may look a little ugly:

```
   int d = (a > b ? a : b) > c ? (a > b ? a : b) : c;
```

or:

```
   int d = a > b ? (a > c ? a : c) : (b > c ? b : c);
```

Answer (score 1):

you *can* do it, because you can nest the ternary operators, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6153949/747128).

The real question is *why* would you want to do it. The readability is going to be terrible. Yuriy Guts' version with the max-functions is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

d = ( a > b ) ? ( ( a > c ) ? a : c  ) : ( ( b > c ) ? b : c )

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
d = new[] { a, b, c }.Max();
```

Which is shorter and in my opinion much more readable than the Math.Max version